# Vertically align 2 different size divs

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I got 2 divs inside parent box.

I want to make the upper one to take 70% of the parent box and the second the other 30%.
I don't want to use position absolute.

Any ideas?

```
**********************
* top div            *
* top div            *
* top div            *
* top div            *
* top div            *
* top div            *
**********************
* bottom div         *
**********************
```

EDIT:
The parent box is floating,

```
#mright {
    width : 45%;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Comment: position relative and absolute, but it breaks overall design. I've also tried using padding and margins but then if the content in the upper dive changes the design is breaking again, table-cell and box align just dont do the trick.

Comment: How about #topDiv{ width: 100%; height: 70%; } #bottomDiv { width: 100%; height: 30%; }

Comment: I wish, but it doesn't work either, both are just bump against each other.

Comment: It sounds like you're floating the elements then. Show us your actual code.

Comment: that is right, the parent element is floating.

Comment: I eddited my answer to include the float and margin and to alter the width. Seems like somethign else is poking your code

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the "top" element has more than 70% worth of content?

Comment: when the content is more I'l' just use overflow:scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I commented above. Is this what you wanted?

```
#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

#parent{
    width: 45%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    margin: 5%;
}

#bottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ggGKe/19/)

Comment: This is what I wan't, the only problem is that the parent height is also in percentage and not absolute number.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ggGKe/17/)?

Having % instead of number should not be a problem. It seems like the problem comes from other place.

Comment: Indeed, I've just now noticed that the out-most div didn't have any height property.

Answer (score 0):

yes, make float:left both the divs; like:

```
#parentDiv{ width:100%; }
#topDiv{ width:70%; }
#bottomDiv{ width: 30%; }
#topDiv,#bottomDiv{ float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.topDiv').height(($(window).height() / 10) * 7);
    $('.bottomDiv').height(($(window).height() / 10) * 3);
    $('.bottomDiv').css('margin-top', $('.topDiv').height());
    $('.bottomDiv').css('margin-left', $('.topDiv').width() * -1);
});
$('.topDiv').height(($(window).height() / 10) * 7);
$('.bottomDiv').height(($(window).height() / 10) * 3);
$('.bottomDiv').css('margin-top', $('.topDiv').height());
$('.bottomDiv').css('margin-left', $('.topDiv').width() * -1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/PzVCR/1/